# How to use mongocompact package in mongoclient connect options

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, driver, golang-migrate

Currently I already use `NewRegistryBuilder()` in the mongo client options , Somehow i want to make use of `NewRespectNilValuesRegistryBuilder()` from [mongocompact](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/mgocompat#NewRespectNilValuesRegistryBuilder) so that I can set the nilvalues in the []models as empty array .

Currently I have something like below , To map the old mgo behavior

```
tM := reflect.TypeOf(bson.M{})
registry := bson.NewRegistryBuilder().RegisterTypeMapEntry(bsontype.EmbeddedDocument, tM).Build()
clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(URI).SetAuth(info).SetRegistry(registry)
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
```

Now somehow I want to incorporate and set the `NewRespectNilValuesRegistryBuilder().Build()` to true in the same connect options , Not sure how to do that . Also the other problem that i see is i'm not able to see the mongocompat registry [file](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v1.11.0/bson/mgocompat/registry.go#L39) in my vendor directory

can i do something like this , `SetRegistry()` two times ? like below ?

```
tM := reflect.TypeOf(bson.M{})
registry := bson.NewRegistryBuilder().RegisterTypeMapEntry(bsontype.EmbeddedDocument, tM).Build()
clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(SOMEURI).SetAuth(info).SetRegistry(registry)
//not sure if the below line is of right usage ??
clientOpts.SetRegistry(NewRespectNilValuesRegistryBuilder().Build())
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
```

can anyone help me with this ?

related issue [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-2137)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this one , All we need to do is

```
registry := mgocompat.NewRegistryBuilder().Build()
connectOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(SOMEURI).SetAuth(info).SetRegistry(registry)
```

This will take care of both requirements , no need to say

```
tM := reflect.TypeOf(bson.M{})
```

Since that's a default behavior that's included in `mgocompat`